# Blackberry - get contacts list

Tags: blackberry, addressbook, contacts

I wanted to get the list of all names and their corresponding email address from the contact list in blackberry JDE 4.7  can anyone help with the code for getting the above mentioned things..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 11):

try this code:

```
public Scr() {
    Vector v = getContacts();
    Enumeration iterator = v.elements();
    while (iterator.hasMoreElements()) {
        String[] contact = (String[]) iterator.nextElement();
        for (int i = 0; i < contact.length; i++)
            add(new LabelField(contact[i]));
    }

}

private Vector getContacts() {
    Vector result = new Vector();
    try {
        BlackBerryContactList contactList = (BlackBerryContactList) PIM
                .getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
        Enumeration enumx = contactList.items();
        while (enumx.hasMoreElements()) {
            BlackBerryContact c = (BlackBerryContact) enumx.nextElement();
            String[] contact = new String[2];
            if (contactList.isSupportedField(BlackBerryContact.NAME)) {
                String[] name = c.getStringArray(BlackBerryContact.NAME, 0);
                String firstName = name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
                String lastName = name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];
                contact[0] = firstName + " " + lastName;
            }
            if (contactList.isSupportedField(BlackBerryContact.EMAIL)) {
                StringBuffer emails = new StringBuffer();
                int emailCount = c.countValues(BlackBerryContact.EMAIL);
                for (int i = 0; i < emailCount; i++) {
                    String email = c.getString(BlackBerryContact.EMAIL, i);
                    if (email != null) {
                        emails.append(email.trim());
                        emails.append("; ");
                    }
                }
                contact[1] = emails.toString();
            }
            result.addElement(contact);
        }
    } catch (PIMException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```